# Set dimensions of NSStepper

Tags: xcode, macos, nsstepper

The `NSStepper` double arrow control is such a tiny little thing. Is there any way I can make it bigger? I haven't been able to find anything about this online.

Comment: It's a built-in interface view, so the size they give you is the size you get. My guess is that either you'll have to try layer-backing the stepper and scale-transforming the layer or else you'll have to roll your own interface view.

Comment: Thx Matt, I was afraid of that 